# Does Git Extensions keep a log of commands and their results?

Tags: git-extensions

When you run a command in Git Extensions, it pops up a window and shows you the git command line that it invokes along with the resulting output. This is handy but sometimes I close the window before I realize that I wanted to look at the details of the output. Does Git Extensions log this output anywhere by default or can it be configured to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like there is no such functionality. You can see the commands issued by Git Extensions from `Help-Gitcommand log'. I guess storing the outputs as well would be too heavy, as the results can be quite lengthy - think of the "Limit number of commits that will be loaded startup" setting. I have a value of 10000 there, and there will be at least that many lines in the output when I just open the program.

Comment: I have mistaken and wrote `https://bitbucket.com/user/repo` into the git remote instead of `https://bitbucket.org/user/repo`. As a result the GE does output `warning: redirecting to https://bitbucket.org/user/repo/` and I could not have a chance to see it. And GE keep asking the credentials for actually *different* domain. Great design for hiding important warnings. -.-

Answer (score 4):

- Git Extensions -> Tools -> Git command Log(F12)
- export to file -> paste to your text editor -> search

[image: Git Extensions Command Log window]